# springboot how to load properties from custom yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a property bean (example):

```
@Data
public class MyProperty {
    private String name;
    private String address;
}
```

and I have a custom yml file in classpath named: `my_property.yml`

```
my.property:
  name: testName
  address: testAddress
```

How to load this file to my property bean?
Not using `@PropertyResource`, because I want to use the yml file.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your point, because Java, do not have Properties like c#.Net . May you try read properties to your application?

Comment: Did you try this annotation before @Value("${name}")  ?

Answer (score 3):

`@PropertySource` is the way to include external/custom properties but unfortunately is doesn't work with yaml files due to [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13912).

You need to load these yaml files on your own by simply writing `EnvironmentPostProcessor` and adding it `META-INF/spring.factories`.

This is described in below Spring documentation (slight difference among versions).
[Spring boot 1.5.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html) 
[Spring boot 2.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are two properties you can look at -

1. spring.config.name - If you don't like application as your file name
   for eg-

   ```
     java -Dspring.config.name = my_property myjar.jar
   ```
2. spring.config.location - To tell where your files lie

More information is well-documented here

[spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html])

Answer (score -2):

Follow: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml

The relative path of `application.yml` file is `/myApplication/src/main/resources/application.yml`.

and access is:

```
@Autowired
private YAMLConfig myConfig;
```

I put my `application.properties` file at `src/main/resources/`
End my `@SpringBootApplication` read.

## application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=***
spring.datasource.username=***
spring.datasource.password=***
```

Comment: sorry, I want a custom .yml file, not a .properties file